# Assume that $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is increasing and continuous from right side

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is increasing and continuous from right side. Then for all $a\leq b$ we have $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}n[\int_b^{b+\frac1n}F(s)\mu(ds)-\int_a^{a+\frac1n}F(s)\mu(ds)]=F(b)-F(a).$$ I don't know how to prove it. I understand it only intuitively  but I can't find any theorem about it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't come by this formula before. However, this is my attemp to solve it.

Let $$ f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}F(s)\mu(ds)$$
Then
$$I = \liminf_{n\to\infty}n[\int_b^{b+\frac1n}F(s)\mu(ds)-\int_a^{a+\frac1n}F(s)\mu(ds)]\\=\liminf_{n\to\infty}n [f(b+\frac{1}{n}) - f(b) + f(a) - f(a+\frac{1}{n})]$$
Let $k = \frac{1}{n}$ and substitute
$$I=\liminf_{k\to 0} \frac{1}{k} [f(b+k) - f(b) + f(a) - f(a+k)]$$
$$I=\liminf_{k\to 0} \frac{f(b+k) - f(b)}{k} - \liminf_{k\to 0} \frac{f(a+k) - f(a)}{k}$$
Each limit is the derivative of $f(x)$ which is $F(X)$ at $b$ and $a$ respectively. Therefore,
$$I=F(b) - F(a)$$